# If $A$ is open, $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Bdry}(A))=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that if $A\subset X$ is open then $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Bdry}(A))=\emptyset$. I have that $\operatorname{Bdry}(A) = \operatorname{Cl}(A)\cap (X-\operatorname{int}(A))=\operatorname{Cl}(A)\cap(X-A)$ because $A$ is open, but I'm stuck in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in\operatorname{Bd}(A)$ implies $x\in\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ intersects with $A$. Now $\operatorname{Bd}(A)^C=(X-\operatorname{Cl}(A))\cup A$ and thus $U$ intersects with $\operatorname{Bd}(A)^C$, which means $x\not\in\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Bd}(A))$.

Comment: I understand, but how can I can conlude that in effect the $int(bd(A))=\emptyset$?

Comment: @andresflorian Simply recall $\text{Int}(\text{Bd}(A))\subseteq\text{Bd}(A)$. (interior of any set is its subset). We proved no $x\in\text{Bd}(A)$ lies in its interior.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in O:=\rm{Int}(\rm{Bd}(A))$. Then $O$ would be a neighbourhood of $x$ that intersects $A$ (as $x \in \rm{Bd}(A)$) and then $O \cap A$ would be a non-empty open set that sits inside $A$ and also intersects $A^\complement$ (as $x \in O \subseteq \rm{Bd}A)$, and this is absurd.